# Is it possible to create an OS X Spotlight app?

Tags: swift, macos, spotlight

Is it possible to create an application where the user would input something in Spotlight and the app would take action? A very simple example would be:

1. User writes "Note: Test note" in Spotlight
2. App grabs "Test note" string and saves it to a text file

Comment: Look up flashlight for spotlight. You can make a plugin trough that.

Comment: I don't think that's possible as of now. There was Flashlight that allowed you to script it with python, but, apparently, that has been made defunct by the recent major update to osx.